# Testing DevExpress controls using pywinauto

Tags: python, devexpress, pywinauto

I'm trying to write simple automated test using pywinauto in a view which is created using devexpress controls. It's a simple listview with 5 columns, but when i try to use `print_control_identifiers` there's like 1000+ lines of output with really long names consisting a lot of random signs. When i tried using swapy, it did show almost nothing.

So my question is if there's any possibility to use pywinauto to automate those controls? Maybe there is some possibility other than pywinauto?

Comment: Probably it's possible, but never tried devexpress controls. Are there some samples publicly available?

Comment: You can download them from `https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/demos.xml` There's a WinForm called "Outlook Inspired App" and You can see there a listview that looks just like the one i'm trying to automate.